# A loop that lets a user enter strings until "q" for quit

Tags: java, loops, parsing, while-loop, do-while

Kind of stumped.  I need the following to loop from the validation point(checks for a comma) so a user can enter text over and over again until "q" is pressed for quitting. I tried putting two loops in there, but I don't know how to repeat the same thing over and over again.  I need the parsing to stay in there for the assignment.

Thanks.

```
  p = 1;
  while(!userName.contains(",")){
  System.out.println("Error: No comma in string ");
  System.out.println("Enter input string: ");
  userName = scnr.nextLine();
  p++;      

 }

  userName = userName.replace(",", "");
  inSS = new Scanner(userName);
  firstName = inSS.next();
  lastName = inSS.next(); 


  System.out.println("First word: " +firstName );
  System.out.println("Second word: " +lastName); 
  p++;


  }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an `if` statement and `break`? 
The break statement leaves the current loop. So, for example, you could add

```
if(scnr.nextLine().equals("q")){
    break;}
```

That will leave the while loop, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that.  Basically, the while loop that is there needs to stay because it is checking to see if a user is inputing a comma or not.  I need the entire piece of this program to loop from the beginning so a user can keep inputing until pressing q.

Comment: By entire piece do you mean what you posted? In that case encapsulate the piece in a second loop (might be best to use do-while) and just keep the while inside of it. Then, use that if statement I posted wherever your input is accepted to break the loop. Though it will only break the current loop, so if it is in the nested while loop it won't quit the whole piece. If you wanted to just terminate the program entirely you could use System.exit(0);

Comment: Yes, what I posted.  The comma check and the parsing afterwards.

Comment: Alright, well perhaps encapsulate it all in a do-while, but initialise a boolean quit right at the beginning of the loop. Inside the nested while loop where there is input, make an if statement that does not use break but instead sets quit to true if q is the input. Then, immediately after the while loop, put another if to check the value of quit. If quit is true, then break. That will break the main do-while. There's probably an easier way to do it but I just can't think of it right now.

Comment: Thats way more than I can think of!  I been at this only a few weeks.  I find its like torture.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: boolean quit; do { while(){//if statement setting quit to true if q is input} if(quit){break;} //parsing code} I think maybe like that. I know it isn't formatted because it's a comment but that's the most basic solution I can think of, unless I'm forgetting something. Hope I could be of assistance, and best of luck.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll see what I come up with.